# To create a new instance of the swt application even when the application is in use

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, e4

I have created a swt application which works fine but i need to create a new instance of the swt application even when the application is already open.for eg how eclipse  opens with new instance each time when application is opened.Please help me how we can create a multiple instances of the application when it is opened.

Comment: Is this a basic SWT application or an Eclipse plugin or Eclipse RCP?

Comment: it is a eclipse rcp application

Comment: It is an e4 rcp application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For e4 applications, there is a bug report [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=330135).

Apparently adding `-data @none` (or setting a different location each time) to your launch configuration is supposed to allow you to launch multiple instances of your e4 application.

However, this only seems to work with "new" builds, so you might have to update yours.

Comment: Can you explain in detail for which options we have to set -data @none in ini file .

Comment: How can we set different location each time or like creating a work space as in eclipse.so after setting the location or workspace a instance should be created in that location